# How do you write a rails migration to remove the :id => false option in the schema.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

How do you write a rails migration to remove the 
    :id => false 
option in the schema.rb? It doesn't seem like this is a method in change_table.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
add_column :models, :id, :primary_key
```